# New blower motor seem to be running too slow

Tags: hvac

I just replaced the blower motor on an older Lenox system. Black high speed wire. White and blue medium wire. The blower seems to be running much slower than expected. Not sure where to go from here. I took out the filter and that helped some but still seems quite slow. It might be notable that until the blower went out, it wouldn't turn off. But I never got around to worry about that. But now it won't cool the home because there's just not enough air coming through. And I'm not sure what to look at at this point. Could the capacitor be causing it to be slow? It seems to start just fine.

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the motor nameplate?

Comment: Is the replacement blower certified, or considered equivalent, by Lenox for the same model?

Comment: compare the "boilerplates" of the two motors.

Comment: It sounds like you may not have the motor wired correctly. Or the new motor is a different speed. Are you only using blue and black? Are both motors the same voltage? Are they similar speeds for the different taps? Photos of the nameplate would be helpful.

Comment: The capacitor is for starting the motor.

Comment: There's a white wire for one of the speeds? That doesn't sound right.... "Yellow: Medium-high ; Blue or brown: Medium-low; Red: Low; **White or purple: Common.**" - You said "high speed wire" I thought for sure you kinda knew what you were talking about.... You wired it back up the same asshat way someone else did with it not shutting off....

Answer (score 0):

Check the RPM rating of both motors, they should be about the same. Validate the color code they may be different. You can always connect it for the other speed to be sure. Check the current rating and draw, they should be about the same. I am assuming it is a squirrel cage fan, is it direct drive or belt driven. If belt driven be sure the pulley is the same size and is tight.You stated: "The blower seems to be running much slower than expected" how did you determine that. Check the condenser, assuming it was working properly before and see if it is icing up, if it is you are correct, if not the speed is probably OK. This should get you close.  Be sure they rotate in the correct direction.

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question but more of a comment.

Comment: I replaced one once.  The speed was determined by the which color wire was connected.   As suggested, and if it's the same type of configuration, try another colored wire.